# Error While Loading Table After Swift 2 Upgrade - IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

When I try to make a dynamic table view with the code below I get the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Any ideas? I checked the array with print() but they are not empty.

```
import UIKit

 class mainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView!


var resultsNameArray = [String]()
var resultsAlloCommentArray = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height


    resultsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight)



    refreshResults()


}




func refreshResults() {


    resultsNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    resultsAlloCommentArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


    let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
    query.includeKey("relUserPointer")
    query.limit = 10

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {

                self.resultsNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as! String)
                self.resultsAlloCommentArray.append(object.objectForKey("relUserPointer")!.objectForKey("settingAllowComment") as! String)

            }


        }
    print(self.resultsNameArray)
        print(self.resultsAlloCommentArray)
         self.resultsTable.reloadData()

    }

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


}




override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {



}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {




    return 10


}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {


return  127

}




    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //here I get the error in the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
     let cell:mainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! mainCell


    cell.profileLbl.setTitle(self.resultsNameArray[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)




    return cell

}




  }
```

Comment: Stop using small letters to start the names of classes. Just stop it. Now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller class declaration says this:

```
class mainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

So this is a UIViewController - *not* a UITableViewController.

Therefore, the cells *cannot* come out of the storyboard as prototype cells. Only a UITableViewController can do that.

So, either you must make this a UITableViewController (here and in the storyboard), or else you must get the cells from somewhere else by calling `registerClass:...` or `registerNib:...` on your table view beforehand.

Finally, and most important, you are calling the wrong method here:

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
```

No. You should call

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:indexPath)
```

That way, you will always get a cell. The way *you* are doing it, you can get `nil` (as you've discovered). You must then make the cell yourself, which you are failing to do; you are not even testing for nil, which is why you are crashing.

One last thing. This has nothing to do with iOS 9 or Swift 2.0. If you think it does, you're just fooling yourself. Your code would have failed in exactly the same way in iOS 8 and Swift 1.2.

Comment: Actually it was working in xcode 6,4 and ios 8 before, now I updated my phone and xcode to 7 lots of uiviewcontrollers are not opening, and tableviews that were working before started to freeze and keep loading without retrieving any data. When I change the UiviewController to Uitableviewcontroller, it says " redundant conformant of mainVC to protocol UItableviewDatasource".

Comment: Yes, that's true about the redundant conformance, so you just delete those protocol declarations. No biggie.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line :

```
     let cell:mainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! mainCell
```

to

```
    let cell:mainCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! mainCell
```